# Why are my apple fritters too doughy in the center?

Tags: deep-frying, apples

I'm making deep-fried apple fritters, and the recipe I am using has me drop them into oil as batter (a bit runny). Dropping them in as batter gives them the kind of crispy-bumpy outside I like.

My problem is that they always end up doughy in the center, because if they cook all the way to the center, the outside will be burnt. I have tried making them more doughy (less water) but that gets rid of the crispy-bumpy outside, and makes them quite dense.

Is there some way for me to make them thinner so that they are not doughy, or how else might I be able to get the center well done, and not lose the crispy-bumpyness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overcooked exterior and undercooked interior indicates that your oil temperature is too high or your fritters are too large. You should be able to solve your problem by frying at a lower temperature and/or making the fritters smaller. 340°F-360°F seems to be the temperature used by many recipes for fritters.